# AWS Cogntio: How to make authentication request in .Net after SignUp/SignIn

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Using AWS SDK for .Net i am able to SignUp user in UserPool using

```
AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials(), RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
SignUpRequest signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest()
        {
            ClientId = CLIENTAPP_ID,
            Password = user.Password,
            Username = user.Username
        };

await provider.SignUpAsync(signUpRequest);
```

After SignUp i want to authenticate user and login and redirect to some authorised page. Using following code i can get Auth Token

```
CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(this.POOL_ID, this.CLIENTAPP_ID, provider);
CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(username, this.CLIENTAPP_ID, userPool, provider);

InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
  {
    Password = password
  };

AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
 if (authResponse.AuthenticationResult != null)
 {
  // Here i can see authResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken
}
```

But now for any next request to GetUserAttributes or DeleteUser, how can i make use of returned user token?
I see that there is `userPool.getCurrentUser();` but this is not available in .Net SDK, its in JS SDK i think.

So how can i make authenticated requests after Signup/SignIn to perform various other operation like UpdateAttributes or DeleteUser etc using .Net SDK or using REST Api calls

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

After the call to StartWithSrpAuthAsync successfully returns, you can use the `user` object and call `GetCognitoAWSCredentials`.

```
CognitoAWSCredentials credentials =
    user.GetCognitoAWSCredentials("identityPoolID", RegionEndpoint.<Your_Identity_Pool_Region>);
```

Then to use those credentials:

```
// examples
await user.UpdateAttributesAsync(...);
await user.DeleteUserAsync();

new AmazonLambdaClient(credentials, AuthenticationManager.Region);
new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

You can also make a call to get the User:

```
string accessToken = authResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;

Task<GetUserResponse> responseTask =
    provider.GetUserAsync(new GetUserRequest
    {
        AccessToken = accessToken
    });

GetUserResponse responseObject = await responseTask;
```

Some references:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cognitoauthentication-extension-library-developer-preview/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/cognito-authentication-extension.html#more-authentication-options
- search `GetCognitoAWSCredentials` within page

Comment: it works for me but how can i use Credentials in web site that use cognito auth? I'd like login without insert user and password